# Android application no more compatible on Market

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play

I've developed an App using level API 10 (2.3.3 SDK version), I've published it on Android Market and all has gone fine. My Application has FINE and COARSE location, INTERNET and NETWORK STATE as uses permission.

Next, I've tried to extend compatibility to level API 8 (2.2). After I've published the new apk on market the App results no more compatible with my device (I've a Samsung GT-I9100, with 2.3.6 Android version).
I've tried to delete cache but nothing, my device is no more compatible.
But if I install the apk via file system the App perfectly works.

**EDIT:**

Here my Android Manifest

```
<manifest package="com.agora.md" android:versionCode="16" android:versionName="1.1.15" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>    
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"/>    
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_md1"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MDApplication" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".service.activity.MDSplashActivity"  
             android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".service.activity.MDMainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".service.activity.MDNewsActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".service.activity.MDMagnificiActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".service.activity.MDNewsDetailsActivity" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity android:name=".service.activity.MDMapActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".service.activity.MDInfoActivity" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".service.activity.MDVolantinoActivity" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".service.activity.MDMapDetailsActivity" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks

### UPDATE

After a month I've checked on Market and now, incredibly, my app is visible on the store. I don't now it's ok because I've made no changes from that.

I think it was a mistake of the store or, probably, a bad value in cache that now has been erased.

However, thanks to all for your support

Comment: Have you changed the version code and version name from what you were using in API level 10 to what you are using here in API level 8?

Comment: Yes, every time I upload a new apk I change the version code and version name.

Comment: what happened then? did you solve it?

Comment: Not again. My app isn't still visible for my android device

Answer (score 0):

The supports-screens tag is used ONLY by the Android market to filter out devices based on the size of screen the device has.  If you don't define a supports-screens tag, then the market doesn't filter them.

However, if you DO define supports-screens any device sizes not listed will default to false.

The Samsung Galaxy SII (your device) I believe is an xlarge screen size.  Change your supports-screens tag to the following:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"  />
```

(note: I added android:xlargeScreens="true")

After that you should see your app in the market again.

Comment: AFAIK, the android:xlargeScreens="true" attribute for the <supports screen> feature is not supported by sdk version 8. The attribute itself was added in API level 9. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge for more info.

Comment: I agree with Ghost. I start to think it's an error of my device, because on GT-I9003 that has a 4'' inch display the app is visible on market

Comment: Marco, did you try the fix? Ghost - you're right.  The Min SDK level could be at 8 and the target SDK level could be at 9.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but Eclipse send me an error and it doesn't generate the apk

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here. I don't have the `supports-screens` tag in my AndroidManifest.xml, but I'm getting incompatibility complaints from users with the Samsung Galaxy S 2 (GT-I9100), Android version 2.3.6. It works with other versions of Android.

Anyone else seen this?