# Android app suddenly not compatible with devices

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app that has been in the Google Play store for about two years now (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dkh.idex) with API level 7+ and support for all screen sizes. It uses a few permissions (ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).

On April 22 2013 I uploaded a version (version code 44) that worked fine on all my users devices. A month later, on May 22 2013 I uploaded a new version with some minor changes (version code 45), but the last few days (starting May 27) a lot of users has complained to me that their devices no longer are compatible with the newest version of my app. These users have been using the app with no such problems for up to two years. Some devices are still able to upgrade to the newest version, but others get the message that their device is not compatible when trying to upgrade (mind you, they already have an older version of the app). I was able to install the application directly through ADB (USB) on a device that said it was not compatible in the Google Play store (a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, old version).

I looked through my changesets of my files, and the only change I have made in the AndroidManifest.xml between the two releases are updating the version code and version number. I have not changed any use permissions, supported screen sizes, supported API levels or even added any activities or changed debug settings.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="dkh.idex"
  android:versionName="3.2.11" android:versionCode="45">

<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application android:name="dkh.classes.MyApp" android:label="@string/app_name"    android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_idex_v3">
    <activity android:name=".idex"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Form2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".InfoForm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".INSTAForm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HygieneForm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CommentForm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddReqChooseForm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddReqForm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FTPForm" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SyncForm" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DrawTestForm" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name="StatisticsForm" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name="PhotoGallery" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name="PhotoView" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name="ParametersForm" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>
    <activity android:name="PropertiesForm" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="InspectionChangeForm" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name="AdvancedSyncWindow" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <service android:process=":image_process" android:name=".ImageUploadService"></service>
    <activity android:name=".HelpWindow" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name="RecoverView"></activity>
    <activity android:name="InspectionCommentForm" ></activity>

</application>
</manifest> `
```

In the rest of my code I have added some texts to my resource files and made some standard minor changes, but nothing that weren't in the app already in some form.

I am really puzzled by this problem. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this or know if Google has changed anything that could have an effect on this? Please ask if you need more information.

Comment: Can this be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924752/android-application-no-more-compatible-on-market

Comment: I can't explain why this issue only recently popped up, but you are missing `android:xlargeScreens` from your `supports-screens` element, which might be related.

Comment: @cloudymusic I thought that `android:anyDensity` would take care of all missing screen sizes? You might be on to something, but it is weird that it haven't been an issue before then.

Comment: @Rick77 It seems like they also recommend adding xlargeScreens to the manifest, but still, it hasn't been an issue before. I will try it later though

Comment: @Daniel Remember that density is a different thing than screen size. :)

Comment: @cloudymusic In the Android developer guide it says that xlargeScreens was introduced in API level 9 while my app is API level 7 (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge). Wouldn't that mean that xlargeScreens is not applicable in my case?

Comment: Okay, it gives me an error when I try to add `android:xlargeScreens` to the manifest, says there is no resource identifier for the attribute in the package `android`

Comment: Same problem here with the same version codes 44, 45 !!! Creepy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem was that Google Play will filter applications based on the device screen size, and because xlargeScreens are not supported in API 7 (version 2.1) the filter will be set to false  on these devices. **This has not been enforced until end of May.** My app had worked on the exact same specification for two years, but I suspect that Google Play has made an update to enforce this constraint.

**The solution:** If you have an app that is developed for API 7 but you want it to be available on xlargeScreens devices, you have to set in your manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

If either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion is 9 or larger, Google Play will allow xlargeScreen devices to see your app.